# How to merge python dictionaries with the same keys, where a particular value will always be overwritten if data is available

Tags: python, dictionary

How would i combine the two dictionaries below to form the new dictionary.
The two dictionaries will either have a number or a Not Found field and i want the Not Found field to always be overwritten by a number. The dictionaries will always have the same keys and only 2 elements in each. This is an example.

```
Dict1: {'MaterialBC': '2261651270620793', 'RFIDBC': 'Not Found'}
Dict2: {'MaterialBC': 'Not Found', 'RFIDBC': '1022010911012012'}

NewDict: {'MaterialBC': '2261651270620793', 'RFIDBC': '1022010911012012'}
```

Is there an easier way to do this other than using if statements for each scenario?

Comment: Using if-statements is pretty low-commitment as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplest I can think of is this,

```
 a = {'MaterialBC': '2261651270620793', 'RFIDBC': 'Not Found'}
 b = {'MaterialBC': 'Not Found', 'RFIDBC': '1022010911012012'}

 c = { k: a[k] if b[k] == 'Not Found' else b[k] for k in a.keys() }
```

It contains an `if` but it is a one-liner.

NB, this will prefer values from `b` if both `a` and `b` contain a number!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def combine(dict1, dict2):
    newDict = {}
    for (key, value) in dict1.items():
        if dict2[key] == "Not Found":
            newDict[key] = value
        else:
            newDict[key] = dict2[key]
    return newDict

>>> dict1 = {'MaterialBC': '2261651270620793', 'RFIDBC': 'Not Found'}
>>> dict2 = {'MaterialBC': 'Not Found', 'RFIDBC': '1022010911012012'}
>>> combine(dict1, dict2)
{'RFIDBC': '1022010911012012', 'MaterialBC': '2261651270620793'}
```

Or:

```
{key: value if dict2[key] == "Not Found" else dict2[key] for (key, value) in dict1.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `"Not Found"`, simply put an empty string when a value is note present. This is so you can take advantage of an empty strings "falsy"-ness. As for your comment about limiting the usage of `if` statements, you can use the ternary form of if statements:

```
>>> d1 = {'MaterialBC': '2261651270620793', 'RFIDBC': ''}
>>> d2 = {'MaterialBC': '', 'RFIDBC': '1022010911012012'}
>>> {k: v if v else d2[k] for k, v in d1.items()}
{'MaterialBC': '2261651270620793', 'RFIDBC': '1022010911012012'}
>>>
```